# How can I detect when Docker is downloading an image from Node / Electron App

Tags: node.js, docker, electron

I am trying to detect when docker is downloading an image from my electron app.

I have the following code

```
  console.log('Starting Docker');
  const childProcess = require('child_process');
  const daemonProcess = childProcess.spawn('docker', commandArgs, {
    detached: true
  });

  daemonProcess.on('error', (err) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('DockerError', err);
      }
    }, 2000);
    writeLog(err);
  });

  daemonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    // Detect Docker is downloading the image.
    // TODO: Inspect Docker Output for 'Downloading' text
    if (mainWindow) {
      mainWindow.webContents.send('DockerInfo', data);
    }
  });
```

The problem is that no actual data is piped out from `daemonProcess.stdout.on` until the docker image actually starts and I don't understand why. It can take a while until the image has downloaded and I want to give feedback to the user.

Comment: There are at least two [community-maintained Node Docker SDKs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/#unofficial-libraries), would using one of these work better than trying to run `docker` as a subprocess?

Comment: Crazy, I did so much searching around Docker and NodeJs yesterday, how come I never came across these? Would have saved me so much time. Please post as an answer and I will accept.